# Replacing last 4 characters with a "*"

Tags: java, string

I have a string and I need to replace the last 4 characters of the string with a "*" symbol. Can anyone please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Do you know `substring()` method of `String` ?

Comment: Note that strings in Java are immutable. So you have to create a new string as shown below by @JigarJoshi. Or use a `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer`) but that would probably be not necessary here.

Comment: @lkuty if you do `str + "****"` under the cover it would use `StringBuilder`

Comment: Didn't know that. Anyway when you use `substring`, you create a new string. That's what I wanted to say. Most method operations on a `String` creates a new `String`. Except `+` as you said. By using a `StringBuilder` I wanted to say that he could use the string to instantiate a `StringBuilder` and then replace the characters in the object without creating a new one and then finally getting a string with `toString `.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick and easy method...

```
public static String replaceLastFour(String s) {
    int length = s.length();
    //Check whether or not the string contains at least four characters; if not, this method is useless
    if (length < 4) return "Error: The provided string is not greater than four characters long.";
    return s.substring(0, length - 4) + "****";
}
```

Now all you have to do is call `replaceLastFour(String s)` with a string as the argument, like so:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        replaceLastFour("hi");
        //"Error: The provided string is not greater than four characters long."
        replaceLastFour("Welcome to StackOverflow!");
        //"Welcome to StackOverf****"
    }

    public static String replaceLastFour(String s) {
        int length = s.length();
        if (length < 4) return "Error: The provided string is not greater than four characters long.";
        return s.substring(0, length - 4) + "****";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The simplest is to use a regular expression:

```
String s = "abcdefg"
s = s.replaceFirst(".{4}$", "****"); => "abc****"
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an example would help:

```
String hello = "Hello, World!";
hello = hello.substring(0, hello.length() - 4);
// hello == "Hello, Wo"
hello = hello + "****";
// hello == "Hello, Wo****"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Model {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="Hello world"; 
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.length()-4)+"****");
    }
}
```

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for but it helped me figure out what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring for this.

```
String str = "mystring";
str = str.substring(0,str.length()-4);
str = str + "****";
```

So substring takes two parameter.

```
substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
```

So, if you call a substring method in a string, It creates a new String that begins from beginIndex inclusive and endIndex exclusive. For example:

```
String str = "roller";
str = str.substring(0,4);
System.out.Println("str");

OUTPUT :

roll
```

so it starts from the beginIndex until the endIndex - 1.

If you want to know more about substring, visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would say, the output is:  str and not roll

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for keeping only the first 3 original characters

```
 /**
 * @param s
 * @return first 3 Characters of s, filled up with * to the Length of s, or s if shorter than 4 Char
 */
static String replaceLastChars(String s) {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(s) || s.length() < 4) {
        return s;
    }
    return StringUtils.rightPad(s.substring(0, 3), s.length(), '*');
}
```

And the corresponding TestCase

```
@Test
public void testReplace() {
    assertThat(replaceLastChars(null)).isNull();
    assertThat(replaceLastChars("")).isEqualTo("");
    assertThat(replaceLastChars("abc")).isEqualTo("abc");
    assertThat(replaceLastChars("abcdfg")).isEqualTo("abc***");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using Javascript slice will solve your problem easy as slice.... check this out.

---

var str = "12345678";
console.log(str.slice(0, -4) + "XXXX");