# How to replace an arbitrary amount of preceding characters in a string with a constant 4 asterisks, excluding the last 3?

Tags: javascript

The result should be something like,

```
console.log(mask('12345')) // **** 345
console.log(mask('12345 6 789')) // **** 789
console.log(mask('1234 5678 9101 1213')) // **** 213
```

I've tried something like,

```
const mask = (string) => `**** ${string.slice(-3)}`
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better approach with regex/`replace`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing last 4 characters with a "\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544234/replacing-last-4-characters-with-a)

Comment: What should the output of `mask('12')` be, where the string has a length smaller than 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach is quite readable in my opinion. But if you want to use a regular expression, one way could be to use `.replace()` to replace all characters in your string, while also grouping the last three using `/.+(.{3})$/`. Then, you can use the group in the replacement string by referring to `$1`:

```js
const mask = string => string.replace(/.+(.{3})$/, "**** $1");
console.log(mask('12345')) // **** 345
console.log(mask('12345 6 789')) // **** 789
console.log(mask('1234 5678 9101 1213')) // **** 213
```

Regex breakdown:

- `.+`: Match any character (one or more)
- `(.{3})$`: Group the last three arbitrary characters. This captured group can be reference using `$1` in the replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression to get only the last 3 numbers

```js
mask = (n) => "**** " + n.match(/(\d{3})$/)[0];
console.log(mask("12345")); // **** 345
console.log(mask("12345 6 789")); // **** 789
console.log(mask("1234 5678 9101 1213")); // **** 213
```

If your numbers could be less than 3 in length you could use this instead

```js
mask = (n) => n.replace(/(.+)(?=(\d){3}$)/g, "****");
if (mask.length != 0) console.log(mask("12345")); // **** 345
console.log(mask("12345 6 789")); // **** 789
console.log(mask("1234 5678 9101 1213")); // **** 213
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var mask = "12345"; //Your characteres to mask
var lastthree = mask.substr(mask.length - 3);
var final = "**** "+lastthree;
```